# Consuming GraphQL with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

Let's say someone has setup a GraphQL endpoint. I want send and consume GraphQL queries from within my Rails application, as opposed to using React and Relay.

Are there examples of this, or known gems or libraries?

Comment: if the endpoint is setup already, just send a regular ajax request with the graphql query in the body--that's the normal way of doing it.

Comment: Do you mean an ajax request from the browser via javascript?

Comment: Sorry I mean an http request.. either as ajax from the browser or from a rails controller... anywhere I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an HTTP request to the GraphQL that's structured in the proper query structure as specified by the GraphQL specification: http://graphql.org/docs/queries/